# Visual studio code doesn't open project folder.

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have different subfolders under my project folder. I could open all of them in visual code other than one folder which was opening previously. When I click on open, the screen is displaying with the folder title but nothing appears on the screen. Please help as I am new to visual studio code

Comment: At the top of the solution explorer is a toggle button "Show All Files" this makes it include all files in the display even if they aren't included in the project. The icons for these will be grayed out a bit.Use the context menu to add these to the project.

Answer (score 9):

This can also be caused by a pending Visual Studio Code update. Close all VS Code windows and if you see a small dialog open stating it's updating VS Code, re-open the folders with VS Code and it should start working again.

Also, try Help > Install Update if VS Code is not updating when you close it down.

This catches me out quite often, I need to pay more attention when an update is pending.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. Right clicking on the side bar and enabling "Explorer" fixed it

Answer (score 2):

try killing all vscode instances and open the folder again.

On my machine vscode's proccess was shown with electron name so killing all electron instances did the job for me.

```sh
killall --signal=9 electron
```

Answer (score 1):

Try right-clicking on the header "Explorer" in the Explorer sidebar where your open folder(s) usually appear. Two options, "Open Editors" and "Folders" will appear. Click "Folders" to make it checked and your folders will appear.

Answer (score 1):

##### SSH connection folder opening issue

For others that may have a more "advanced" problem, like in the case of Opening Folders from an SSH connection: consider that there may be a hanging VSCode process that was previously attached to the folder, and that disallows re-opening it.

Rebooting the machine helped me in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As [suggested on this GitHub issue by isidorn](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/104190#issuecomment-670378079), copy and paste this in your terminal:

```
code --user-data-dir PATH_TO_SOME_FOLDER_WHERE_VSCODE_WILL_STORE_TMP_DATA
```

It opens a new vscode editor and you should be able to open your project :)